# Select() method and option() method works differently

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

Today I have seen a question in selenium C# section where this question was posted, I try to solve that problem through WATIR coding, I have written the below code and WATIR identifies this select list as invisible.

```
b.goto 'http://automationpractice.com/index.php'
b.img(title: 'Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts').click
b.iframe(xpath: "//*[starts-with(@id,'fancybox-frame')]").select_list.select("L")
```

But If I select that same select_list through below metioned code, it works fine.

```
b.iframe(xpath: "//*[starts-with(@id,'fancybox-frame')]").select_list.option(text: "L").click
```

I don't understand what is the difference here, when I put a debug pointer, both are making a selenium call to `find_element(tag_name: "select")`, first one fails due to element invisible but second one passes

@Titus, @JustinKo Can you please explain me what's happening here? what's the difference?

Note: Please run it in Chrome.

Comment: Your first locator is full of indices which is not good. They are more brittle and more likely that the element will change and you start clicking on an element that you weren't expecting to click on. It would be better if you did something simple like a CSS selector, e.g. `a.quick-view-mobile`. Or better yet, click on the link by product name and skip the popup dialog all together. Then you could provide the product name and click on that product instead of clicking on "the first product" which would likely change regularly on an actual store site.

Comment: If you clicked on the product link itself, it navigates to the product page instead of hosting it in the dialog with an IFRAME. You might try that and get more consistent behavior? Are you sure it's not a timing issue?

Comment: @JeffC Hi, clicking that image is not a problem for me, for an example, I have updated my code, you may have the look at it. My problem is in the select_list, In WATIR, you can choose `b.select_list.select('something')` or `b.select_list.option(text: 'something').select`, for me , first one throws the invisibility error but second one succeeds.

Comment: Also, this is more readable and does the same thing: `b.iframe(id: /^fancybox-frame/).select_list.option(text: "L").click`

Comment: @titusfortner that's awesome , Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving from a comment to an answer:

The issue is that we refactored the normal (non-select-list) way of doing it to not check for whether an element is displayed ahead of time, and put the waiting logic in the rescue block if Selenium complained. The select-list code is still checking the visibility ahead of time, and this particular select-list element is not displayed according to Selenium. Since it appears that Selenium can select options without select list showing as displayed, Watir should not be waiting for this.

I've fixed it here, and it will be working in Watir 6.13 (should be released "soon")

https://github.com/watir/watir/commit/77af164fcdecb71d8d2240110d3fb4b1dabeee4b

Comment: So select() method will choose the option as well? Or option() method will throw the error?

Comment: select() method will choose the option. Also, 6.13 is released so you can try it out.

Comment: Hi your modification is not waiting for select list to exist, it immediately throws the error.

Comment: @Rajagopalan This is a different bug that has to do with collections which means fixing how we are ensuring context so that it can apply equally to elements and collections, and the fix is here: https://github.com/watir/watir/pull/771

Comment: okay, I would revert back to my earlier version until this get fixed.

Comment: Selenium is detecting a particular select list as invisible through `displayed?` method but it can select the option in the select list, so it appears that select element is hidden but option is not, eh?

Comment: No, Selenium intentionally doesn't evaluate the displayedness of option, so Watir unnecessarily was checking for it.

Comment: Selenium doesn't do any checking but wedriver does the visibility checking before it clicks the element that's what I meant.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Selenium specifically does *not* check visibility for option elements. For other elements, yes.

Comment: It obviously checks the visibility of option element. But whether some element is visible or not is clearly depends on the ability of the driver, For an example I work in an application called IDIT in which options are visible to chrome driver but it's hidden to the geckodriver. Please don't think that options are hidden because it seems to be appearing while you click the select list, since size of the select list is always zero it appears to be hidden but it is not , so it's not hidden in a normal select list. And once again, selenium doesn't check the visibility but web driver does

Comment: @Rajagopalan No. Selenium does not check the visibility of an option. The isShown atom specifically ignores that element.

Comment: I am also saying selenium doesn't check, but web driver does the checking.

Comment: Seriously no; no it doesn't. The drivers use the isShown atom built by the Selenium project. It ignores visibility. This is why you don't have to click on the Select List object before clicking on an option. Because it doesn't check for visibility.

Comment: You don't have to click the select_list,that's because option is one of the element is webpage and that element is located by the xpath `//select[@id='xxx']/option[normalize-space()='yyyy']` so you don't have to click the select_list to choose the option. You still miss my point of select list size by default is zero. so all elements are visible.

Comment: I didn't get that far in parsing your comment because your assumptions for it are wrong. I'm giving an example for option elements being treated differently than other elements. If isShown atom did not treat option elements differently, you would have to click select list to display the options to the user before being able to click the option. It has nothing to do with how you locate them. Also Selenium is an implementation of the WebDriver spec, so these two things can't behave differently, they are the same.